# DateTime Saved loses time portion

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datetime, cookies

I have a Datetime String Saved to a cookie as below

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    LoginDate = date.ToString("u", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).Replace("Z", "");
    int sessionTimeout = 1;
    DateTime dateExpress = date.AddMinutes(sessionTimeout);
    ExpressDate = dateExpress.ToString("u", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).Replace("Z", "");
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["express"];

    if (cookie == null)
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("express");
    }
    cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    cookie.Path = "/";
    cookie.Values["express"] = ExpressDate;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

This work as expected as I can see in the Application tab that cookie has saved correctly

[Please refer the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko718.jpg)

But when I access it from the client side it only returns the date bit losing the time portion.

```
var current = getCookie("express");
    var date = current.split(" ")[0];
    alert(date);
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your express contains `express=2017-01-16 09:07:49` and when we split it apart by space you will get two string in which first will be date and another next would be time. Thus you have to do something like this to get the date and time separated.

```
var current = getCookie("express");
var date = current.split(' ')[0];
var intime = current.split(' ')[1];
alert(date);
alert(intime);
```

Whereas the `current.split(" ")[0];` will give you expression like `express=2017-01-16` and thus I believe you should break this apart using `=` again to get the date only.

or else if you are looking for date and time in one variable you can do something like this

```
var current = getCookie("express");
var smDateTime = current.split('=')[1];
alert(smDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

your cookie is in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

split that string on a space ... `.split(" ")` ... you get an array

```
["yyyy-mm-dd", "hh:mm:ss"]
```

element [0] is "yyyy-mm-dd"

solution

```
var date = getCookie("express");
alert(date);
```